# React.js, inside useEffect hook, window.location.href will not stop break further code from execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, window.location

Recently I found out, if I use `window.location.href` to do a redirection, and I do not specify `return {}`, the further code will continue to execute and that is not what I wanted.

May I please ask for some clarification, if this is related to:

1. React.js `useEffect` hook.
2. `window.location.href` by default will not break after redirection.
3. Async-await.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const myFunction = () =>
      ajax({
        url: API_ROUTES.MY_EXAMPLE_ROUTE,
        requestBody: {
          request_message: "Hi, pls help!",
        },
        handleSuccess: response => {
          if (condition === true)) {
            window.location.href = "http://google.com";
            // If I do not put return here, code will continue to execute.
            return {}; 
          }
         
          // Code that I do not want to run after redirection
          history.push(routes.error);
          return {};
        },
        handleError: error => {
          history.push(routes.error);
        },
      });
    const init = async () => {
      await myFunction();
    };
    init();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to expect the code to stop executing the function after setting the `window.location.href` to a value, but that's incorrect. To exit a function prematurely, you would indeed need to use a `return`.

A better solution would be to use an `else` condition, so that `history.push` only runs when `condition` is false.

```js
if (condition) {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
} else {
  history.push(routes.error);
}
```